# Apache Camel Regex Operator not matching

Tags: regex, spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to use Apache Camel (with Spring XML) to check if a message body matches a regex:

```
<when>
    <simple>${body} regex 'https?://(?:www\.)?twitter\.com[^\w]+'</simple>
    <to uri="activemq:queue:test"/>
</when>
```

So `http://www.twitter.com/user` in the body of a message should be moved to the 'test' queue.

The regex matches in Rad Regular Expression Designer, but Camel is still not moving the message to the 'test' queue. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: will it work on any regex? Have you written a test case?

Comment: Yes it does work on a really basic regex.. I think the issue could be that its partially matching in the Rad Designer App, but then Camel is looking for a full match. If that's the case then maybe I need to investigate whether regex in camel can be switched to partial match of some kind.

Comment: Camel is using the JDK reg exp so I suggest to write some java code to test the reg exp to get it working in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util.regex requires a full match, so if that is what Apache Camel uses (?) then your hypothesis is correct.  Wouldn't the easiest fix be to put ".*" before and after the regex?

Comment: That's true only if you use the `matches()` method; `find()` does substring matching like most other regex tools.  However, this is the only reason I can see why that regex would fail, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
<simple>${body} regex '(?:https?://)?(?:w{3}\.)?twitter\.com(?:/.*|/)?'</simple>
```

which contains some slight modifications. The biggest is the wildcard .* at the end, so that it matches anything afterwards (as long as it has the slash first).

Thanks for the help and for suggesting the .*